# PHP: Check for existence and declare function in one line

Tags: php, function

Is there a way to check if a function exists already, and then declare it in the same line if it doesn't, without using `if`?

I'm aware that it's possible to do

```
if (!function_exists('func')) function func() {}
```

but for academic reasons I'm curious if there are different ways to do that. Perhaps something along the lines of

```
function_exists('func') or function func() {}
```

or

```
(function_exists('func') ? '' : function func() {})
```

but actually works?

It seems that you can actually declare an anonymous function using the first syntax:

```
function_exists('func') or function() {}
```

but that's no good because the function doesn't have a name...

And it's also possible to assign the function to a variable,

```
function_exists('func') or $func = function() {};
```

but the function isn't in the global scope doing it that way.

Comment: It's possible to do `if (!function_exists('func')) function func() {}`? [Are you sure about that?](https://3v4l.org/rQ81Q)

Comment: @Don'tPanic Not anymore I'm not...

Comment: It looks like it's possible to do if you wrap it in a function call, but not if it's just inside `<?php` tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only other way I can think of to do this is to have `func()` declared in an include

```
function_exists('func') or include('func.php');
```

Of course, if it's in an include, you can do it much more simply by doing it like this

```
include_once('func.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering all PHP functions are declared globally, it escapes me why you'd have to check if a function already exists or not (or why it must be checked without using an `if` statement).

Unless of course you have it declared in some other php file that is not included on your current page assuming you are building a web application.

However there is a a [php function that checks if a function exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php), but depending on your logic you'd still have to use some sort of `if` statement.

```
if (!function_exists('my_function')) {
    //delcare function...
}
```

To answer your question: No. There's not really a way to do this other than as you described, simply because there is no reason to do it any other way.